# Windows Server 2008 R2 - How to copy a scheduled task

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

I would like to create a new scheduled task that is extremely similar to an existing task.  It would be a pain to write down or type out all the settings.

Is there a way to copy an existing task to create a new one?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Right click on the task you want to duplicate.
2. Click export, save it somewhere
3. On your right hand side, under Action, click Import task
4. Choose the file you've just export
5. A new windows will popup revealing the property of imported task, rename the task and adjust your task accordingly.

Comment: uhm, this is bad design, but it works

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a task created you can right-click it and Export it to an XML file.  You can then Import that XML back into the Task Scheduler as many times as you'd like to create new tasks that are the same.